# What are the relation between package configuration and protection level in ssis

Tags: ssis

If we create a package configuration in SSIS,whether it will overrride the protection level we created? Or,If i am creating a XML configuration on my package what protection level is best for me?Is it necessary to create configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this blog by [Matthew Roche](http://bi-polar23.blogspot.com/2009/04/ssis-and-package-protectionlevel.html). It will give you good guidance and understanding of the protection levels in SSIS.